# AngularJS how to get label and value from selected

Tags: angularjs

I have a dropdown (select) that is populated via web api. The return of the web api has the following structure:

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Description": "A description"
}
```

What I need is, when I select an option I want to have de corresponding label (or text) and value. This is what I have:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="requestTypeList"
    ng-change="selectChange"
    ng-options="requestType.Id as requestType.Description for requestType
    in requestTypes">
</select>

<input type="text" ng-model="RequestTypeID" /><br/>
<input type="text" ng-model="RequestTypeDescription" />
```

My controller looks like this:

```
(function (app) {
    var requestCtrl = function ($scope, $http, requestTypeService) {

    $scope.requestRows = [];

    $scope.selectChange = function() {
        $scope.RequestTypeID = $scope.requestTypeList.value;
        $scope.RequestTypeDescription = $scope.requestTypeList.label;
    }

    requestTypeService.getAll().success(function (data) {
        $scope.requestTypes = data;
    });


    $scope.addRequest = function () {

        var requestRow = {
            RequestTypeID: $scope.RequestTypeID, // Here I need the selected value
            RequestTypeDescription: $scope.RequestTypeDescription, // Here I need the selected Description
            EventColor: $scope.EventColor
        };

        $scope.requestRows.push(requestRow);
    };

    $scope.removePlanboardRequest = function (index) {
        $scope.planboardRequests.splice(index, 1);
    };
};

app.controller("PlanboardRequestCtrl", planboardRequestCtrl);
}(angular.module("planboardApp")));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `ng-options` to select the whole object instead of just it's ID .

Also fix missing `()` in `ng-change`

Fix invalid `label` and `value` properties in `selectChange ()`

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="requestTypeList"
    ng-change="selectChange()"
    ng-options="requestType as requestType.Description for requestType
    in requestTypes">
</select>
```

JS

```
$scope.selectChange = function() {
    $scope.RequestTypeID = $scope.requestTypeList.Id;
    $scope.RequestTypeDescription = $scope.requestTypeList.Description;
}
```

By setting ng-options to select whole object you really wouldn't need to use individual variables like `RequestTypeID` and  `RequestTypeDescription` since everything you need for the view or for `$http` is already in `requestTypeList`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set `ng-model` of `ng-options` to receive the `object` instead of `id`.

Also In your cause I think there's no necessity to use `ng-change` directive, you can simply set ng-model attributes to the inputs, as follows:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.requestTypes = [  
         {  
            "Id":1,
            "Description":"First description"
         },
         {  
            "Id":2,
            "Description":"Second description"
         },
         {  
            "Id":3,
            "Description":"Third description"
         }
      ];
    });
})();
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  Requesters: <select class="form-control" ng-model="requestTypeList" ng-options="requestType as requestType.Description for requestType in requestTypes">
  </select>
  <hr>
  <label for="requestId">Id: </label>
  <input type="text" id="requestId" ng-model="requestTypeList.Id">
  <br>
  <label for="requestDesc">Description: </label>
  <input type="text" id="requestDesc" ng-model="requestTypeList.Description">
</body>

</html>
```